# Solidity: Error when deploying the voting tutorial; problem with constructor and array?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I tried to reproduce the voting tutorial from the solidity homepage [https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/solidity-by-example.html#voting]. I encountered the following problem: The code can be compiled withouth an error, but when i want to "deploy" it in the JVM i always get errors. I think the problem is connected to the constructor who expects a bytes32 array.

Here are the error messages, depending on what parameter i used with the "Deploy" button in remix.

> a) "Name1", "Name2"
>   --> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":2},
>   value={"types":["bytes32[]"],"values":["Name1","Name2"]},
>   version=4.0.36)
>
> b) ["Name1", "Name2"]
>   --> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes32 value (arg="", coderType="bytes32", value="Name1",
>   version=4.0.36)
>
> c) "Name1"
>   --> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value (arg="", coderType="array", value="Name1",
>   version=4.0.36)
>
> d) ["Name2"]
>   --> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid bytes32 value (arg="", coderType="bytes32", value="Name2",
>   version=4.0.36)
>
> e) Name3
>   --> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 1
>
> f) 'Name3'
>   --> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
>
> g) ['Name4']
>   -->creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

/// @title Voting with delegation.
contract Ballot {
    // This declares a new complex type which will
    // be used for variables later.
    // It will represent a single voter.
    struct Voter {
        uint weight; // weight is accumulated by delegation
        bool voted;  // if true, that person already voted
        address delegate; // person delegated to
        uint vote;   // index of the voted proposal
    }

    // This is a type for a single proposal.
    struct Proposal {
        bytes32 name;   // short name (up to 32 bytes)
        uint voteCount; // number of accumulated votes
    }

    address public chairperson;

    // This declares a state variable that
    // stores a `Voter` struct for each possible address.
    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

    // A dynamically-sized array of `Proposal` structs.
    Proposal[] public proposals;

    /// Create a new ballot to choose one of `proposalNames`.
    constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames) public {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

        // For each of the provided proposal names,
        // create a new proposal object and add it
        // to the end of the array.
        for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            // `Proposal({...})` creates a temporary
            // Proposal object and `proposals.push(...)`
            // appends it to the end of `proposals`.
            proposals.push(Proposal({
                name: proposalNames[i],
                voteCount: 0
            }));
        }
    }

    // Give `voter` the right to vote on this ballot.
    // May only be called by `chairperson`.
    function giveRightToVote(address voter) public {
        // If the first argument of `require` evaluates
        // to `false`, execution terminates and all
        // changes to the state and to Ether balances
        // are reverted.
        // This used to consume all gas in old EVM versions, but
        // not anymore.
        // It is often a good idea to use `require` to check if
        // functions are called correctly.
        // As a second argument, you can also provide an
        // explanation about what went wrong.
        require(
            msg.sender == chairperson,
            "Only chairperson can give right to vote."
        );
        require(
            !voters[voter].voted,
            "The voter already voted."
        );
        require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
    }

    /// Delegate your vote to the voter `to`.
    function delegate(address to) public {
        // assigns reference
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(!sender.voted, "You already voted.");

        require(to != msg.sender, "Self-delegation is disallowed.");

        // Forward the delegation as long as
        // `to` also delegated.
        // In general, such loops are very dangerous,
        // because if they run too long, they might
        // need more gas than is available in a block.
        // In this case, the delegation will not be executed,
        // but in other situations, such loops might
        // cause a contract to get "stuck" completely.
        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)) {
            to = voters[to].delegate;

            // We found a loop in the delegation, not allowed.
            require(to != msg.sender, "Found loop in delegation.");
        }

        // Since `sender` is a reference, this
        // modifies `voters[msg.sender].voted`
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Voter storage delegate_ = voters[to];
        if (delegate_.voted) {
            // If the delegate already voted,
            // directly add to the number of votes
            proposals[delegate_.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        } else {
            // If the delegate did not vote yet,
            // add to her weight.
            delegate_.weight += sender.weight;
        }
    }

    /// Give your vote (including votes delegated to you)
    /// to proposal `proposals[proposal].name`.
    function vote(uint proposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(sender.weight != 0, "Has no right to vote");
        require(!sender.voted, "Already voted.");
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = proposal;

        // If `proposal` is out of the range of the array,
        // this will throw automatically and revert all
        // changes.
        proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    /// @dev Computes the winning proposal taking all
    /// previous votes into account.
    function winningProposal() public view
            returns (uint winningProposal_)
    {
        uint winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
            if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
                winningProposal_ = p;
            }
        }
    }

    // Calls winningProposal() function to get the index
    // of the winner contained in the proposals array and then
    // returns the name of the winner
    function winnerName() public view
            returns (bytes32 winnerName_)
    {
        winnerName_ = proposals[winningProposal()].name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want `["0x4e616d653100000000000000000000", "0x4e616d653200000000000000000000"]` (an array of two 32-byte hexadecimal values).

Comment: Check out this link:
(It worked for me)
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50310/how-to-pass-the-value-in-bytes32-array

Comment: Thx  smarx, i got the idea, although your values dont work. Thx @ameeshaagrawal, the answer in the link worked. Somehow i find the variable name a bit misleading ("proposalNames" not proposalBytes...). In addition I somehow remembered that string and bytes32 can be handled equally (whats obviosly wrong). However, thx for help. This was my first question here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use strings since the function is expecting an array composed of bytes32 values. Link posted by @Ameesha (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50310/how-to-pass-the-value-in-bytes32-array) shows how to encode the strings to bytes32. Additionally, I learned that passing values in single quotes is *wrong*, and not enclosing values in square brackets is also *wrong*... the *correct way* is to use double quotes around each hex value and use square brackets to represent as a list. So, for instance, "Proposal A", "Proposal B", "Proposal C" encodes to:

```
["0x50726f706f73616c204100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
 "0x50726f706f73616c204200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "0x50726f706f73616c204300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument of []address as  : [ "address","address1" ] instead of [address,address2].